# get all input field id and value as key value that are in a table

Tags: lightning-aura-components, js

I have a table that contains dynamic no of input fields. I want to get the input id and the value of these input fields in js as key-value pair.

```
 <table>
    <tbody>
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.lists1}" var="list1">
            <tr>
                <td>{!list1.Name}</td>
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.lists2}" var="list2">
                    <td><input id="{!list2.Name+'-'+list1.Name}" value="{!list1.Name}"></input></td>
                </aura:iteration>
            </tr>
        </aura:iteration>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

cmp

```
<aura:component >
<aura:attribute name="lists1" type="List" default="[{Name:'red1'}, {Name:'green1'}, {Name:'blue1'}]" />
<aura:attribute name="lists2" type="List" default="[{Name:'red2'}, {Name:'green2'}, {Name:'blue2'}]" />
<table>
    <tbody>
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.lists1}" var="list1">
            <tr>
                <td>{!list1.Name}</td>
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.lists2}" var="list2">
                    <td><input id="{!list2.Name+'-'+list1.Name}" class="inp" value="{!list1.Name}"></input></td>
                </aura:iteration>
            </tr>s
        </aura:iteration>
    </tbody>
</table></aura:component>
```

rendered

```
({
afterRender : function(component, helper) {
    this.superAfterRender();
    let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.inp');
    for (var i = 0 ; i < inputs.length ; i++) {
        console.log(inputs[i].id + ' ' + inputs[i].value)
    }
}
```

})

Comment: Good solution but don't use `id` attributes as Aura may overwrite them (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_ids.htm). Use the input's `name` attribute instead.

Comment: I tested it and it worked correctly but you are right. I usually use data-prop for cases like this